# Ember, JSON and IE8. Unable to display data

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-8

I am connecting to an API using a RESTAdapter. This seems to work well in IE9 and upwards. For some reason, when I'm trying to view the data in IE8, I get "Error while processing route: campaigns.index" and nothing else.

The software versions I'm using to create the Ember App is:

```
Ember      : 1.8.1 
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a 
Handlebars : 1.3.0 
jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

I have tried changing the versions using bower so they are still compatible but I still get an error regarding the index with no explanation.

My route is:

```
TM.CampaignsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){      
        return this.store.find("campaign")
    } 
});
```

My models attributes are being defined as:

```
TM.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
    campaign_name: DS.attr(),
    campaign_code: DS.attr(),
    desc: DS.attr(),
    effective_from: DS.attr(),
    products: DS.attr(),
    type: DS.attr()
});
```

The JSON is setup as:

```
{
   "campaigns":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "campaign_name":"Necessitatibus et.",
         "campaign_code":"YQADM",
         "desc":"1",
         "effective_from":"2014-11-24 14:33:07",
         "products":"Loans",
         "type":"Gold"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "campaign_name":"Voluptatem sequi adipisci necessitatibus.",
         "campaign_code":"VFYGTO",
         "desc":"1",
         "effective_from":"2014-11-24 14:33:07",
         "products":"Loans",
         "type":"Gold"
      }
   ],
   "meta":{
      "per_page":10,
      "total":30
   }
}
```

To get a better understanding of where it was failing with IE 8, I turned on LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL and it fails when attempting to call the afterModel hook

```
Attempting transition to campaigns 
Transition #1: campaigns: calling beforeModel hook 
Transition #1: campaigns: calling deserialize hook 
Transition #1: campaigns: calling afterModel hook 
Transition #1: campaigns.index: calling beforeModel hook 
Transition #1: campaigns.index: calling deserialize hook 
Error while processing route: campaigns.index 
Transition #1: campaigns.index: transition was aborted
```

I don't receive any errors regarding Object.create because I'm using the shim to combat this and it seems to work fine.

I have considered reading about creating Ember qunit tests in order to get more information. Is this the right direction to look into or is there some configuration for IE 8 which I'm missing?

Unfortunately, I have to build this app to support IE8 and I'm enjoying using Ember so I'm hoping I can stick with it.

Comment: This might be unrelated since you're using beta-8, but since beta-9 Ember-data has required a shim for IE8. Might've been to fix this bug, might not, but it's the only IE8 issue I can think of. Take a look at the Object.create section (http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html). Might wanna try upgrading.

Comment: Unfortunately the data still doesn't appear in IE8.

Comment: I have tried using Ember Model and just $.getJSON and I'm still having the problem with displaying the data. I'm starting to think it's got something to do with the way IE8 handles promises since this error happens when afterModel hook is calling...

Comment: Can you post your templates and possible a jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

So I started again and stripped away every plugin I had. I'm using Laravel along with Ember to create my application. The Laravel Debug bar was preventing the model from appearing in IE8.

Thanks for your efforts Nicholas. Much appreciated.